# Should I connect my redux-form to react-redux with connect

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a question about redux-form. It's not really an issue, it's more like a question about best practises. I've been using redux and erikras/redux-form for several years now and feel really comfortable with it. I remember clearly that, when I first learned how to use redux, my colleagues at the time told me that I should only connect containers component to redux. What I mean by container component is, a component which is supposed to be a whole screen/web page (and thus it would never be used by another component, other than a router off course). And so I kept on respecting this rule without questioning it until this day.

But when reading latest redux form documentation, it seems that if we want to check the value of our form in the form's component, we are supposed to use a formValuesSelector in a react-redux connect mapStateToProps. And in the documentation, the form is directly connected to redux with react-redux's connect function.

My question is: Is it ok to connect my form to redux eventhough I already connected the container component which contains my form ? Isn't it bad practice ? Off course I could fetch my form values from the container's mapStateToProps and pass it to my form with props but I feel like my code would get messier and my container would re-render more than it should.

Any help, comment or suggestion would be appreciated, I'm very curious about this matter because I'm eager to improve my code.

Comment: so what you mean is your form is a component that you want to connect to your store to retrieve form data and the form container(parent) is already connected to store right?

Comment: @adel Yes, indeed. For more clarificiation, I intend to use this selector: https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/

Comment: ofc this not bad practice, why you are using redux ? to store you app state in one place(store) and make each component access any state that it needs from this store. the form container doesn't need this state!